# Viewing or importing *.pbf file (OSM data, binary format) in ArcGIS Desktop or QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, editing

How to view or import a pbf file (OSM data,binary format) in ArcGIS Desktop or QGIS?

Are any 3rd party applications needed?

I would like to edit this file on any GIS Software.

Answer (score 3):

The ArcGIS Editor for OSM (https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-osm-editor) should allow you to do what you want to do.  Data is downloaded via the Xapi.

QGIS has an OpenStreetMap Plugin:  http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/QGIS_OSM_Plugin

I have only used the QGIS plugin, and it worked well.

Comment: OSM Plugin page now says: "This plugin no longer works with current OSM data, or with current versions of QGIS."

Answer (score 1):

I tried using GDAL, but this is difficult for non-programmers.

This option is way more efficient and easy:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert

You can convert the file to an .osm, which can be opened through the ArcGIS for OSM tool.